# Why wasn't this caught by the low quality filter?

Tags: support, status-completed, low-quality-posts

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338301/welcome-to-the-discussion-thread-for-nokia-location-apis has somehow survived for over a month. The user in question also created the tag wiki and excerpt.

As it has both "thread" and "discussion" in the title I would have thought this should have been caught by the low quality filter. Shouldn't it have been?

I can't find any evidence on the [Nokia Forums](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/forumdisplay.php?280-Nokia-Location-APIs) that they're attempting to move them here but this seems to be relatively strange if it wasn't created by an employee.

Comment: It's not closed yet so if someone want to help please do!

Comment: Closed and voted to delete.

Comment: Aaaand it's gone.

Comment: @jolly, why is this [status-completed]? Getting the question removed was a secondary goal (a side effect of posting it on meta) my question is why wasn't it caught by the low quality algorithm at the time of posting?

Comment: The low quality filter is not designed to catch stuff like this.  The post was perfectly capitalized and grammaticized.  What you're describing is a filter that can evaluate the content, like a human being can. Computers aren't that smart.

Comment: I had always assumed (and I think it's been implied on meta before) that it also uses keywords @Robert. If that's not the case then fair enough.

Comment: It looks at some words, but I don't see anything in there that's detectable.  The OP even avoided the usual "Hello" and "Thanks in advance" traps.

Comment: On a related note, the question itself escaped human moderation most likely because it was completely uninteresting, and didn't get sufficient views to close.  The new review queues seem to help immensely in that regard, especially on the smaller sites like Programmers.SE

Comment: Shouldn't "discussion" and "thread" be part of the list @RobertHarvey. I would definitely agree that the low quality queue has helped massively but I would have thought it would have helped more on the bigger sites where some stuff is more likely to get missed? I'm happy to be wrong though :-).

Comment: Possibly.  My understanding of the way this works is that SE did a statistical analysis on the word usage patterns of many questions, and found the smallest subset of words that catch, say, 90 to 95 percent of the worst questions.  The resulting word list is not what you might expect ("problem" is in the list, at least for titles, but "discussion" is apparently not).  Note that "thread" is an actual programming term, having to do with concurrency.